# How to create a finite state machine that can process simultaneous events

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, state-machine, fsm

Suppose you have an object 'A' that can potentially receive the following events from external objects:

Event 1

Event 2

...

Event n

Now suppose that the framework that hosts 'A' is such that all relevant events will be delivered to 'A' (one at a time), and then A::doEval() will be called.

It's important to note that 'A' could receive any combination of events in any order.  'A' might only get one event before doEval() is called, or it might get 5 events before doEval() is called.  There's no way to know ahead of time.

It's also important to note that these events, because they are all delivered to 'A' before A::doEval() is called, should be considered simultaneous events.  A regular state machine would react to each event as it was handed to 'A'.  This would be incorrect in my usage case...  I need 'A' to sit back and collect all events, and only in doEval() should 'A' perform any actions.

Now here's the trick bit:  The doEval() logic needs to realize that only a subset of events occurred, but that it might need factor them all in.  For example, the code (this is ugly and what I'm trying to avoid) might look like this:

```
doEval()
    if(Event 1 occurred && Event 2 occurred) then <do something>
```

It's that 'if' statement...  I only want to perform the action if both events occurred, but I don't want to have that 'if' statement. This is what FSMs are supposed to get rid of right?  Do I need to have a hierarchy of state machines?

Any ideas on the "proper" way to address this?  Any links or papers to read would be great, code is even better.

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a literature on "Asynchronous Finite-State Machines", eg. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470987629.ch9/summary Perhaps that would help.

Comment: Maybe the answer is using bit-masks. Each elementary event has a unique (power of 2) identifier. The set of events are ORed to have a macro-event. An action table (macro-event, action) is initialized (usually a hash table) to redirect quickly to the appropriate action...

Comment: These are both great answers -- thanks!  I seem to have stumbled across at least the beginnings of what I'm looking for in literature about Moore and Mealy state machines, the difference being that Mealy SM outputs are dependent on state + input (like a traditional FSM), and Moore outputs are only dependent on state, which can be mutated multiple times before evaluation to an output.  I will keep reading and post anything here that I find.  Thx again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for in the form of Harel State Machines:

http://www.mathworks.com/videos/understanding-state-machines-harel-state-machines-4-of-4-90491.html

TL/DR: Take what we all know as state machines and add the ability to have hierarchical substates, parallel state machines, and communication between independent state machines (which he calls broadcasting).

Answer (score 0):

Make a queue to gather all events directed to "A" and pop them from queue and then process events.

Comment: Good idea, but (because I did a poor job expressing my requirements) it won't work.  Let me elaborate in the original text.... One second.

Comment: Based on your new requirement, what you can do is keep on gathering event. And after receiving each event, call doEval(). In that case you know which events you have received and what action you need to take. But in this case you need a condition by which you an decide to reset you state to init.

Answer (score 0):

The whole job of a state machine is to capture the *relevant* history of events in a succinct way. A state machine exactly allows you to **avoid** the checks of the kind:

```
doEval()
    if(Event 1 occurred && Event 2 occurred) then <do something>
```

The Mathworks video is a good starting point, but I would also recommend the following sources:

- [UML state machine (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UML_state_machine)
- [A crash course in UML state machines (Embedded.com article)](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4008247/A-crash-course-in-UML-state-machines-Part-1)
- [Back to Basics (CUJ article)](http://www.drdobbs.com/back-to-basics/184401737)